# Submitting App with CloudKit to App Store is required Demo Account?

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

I'm developing an app with CloudKit and want to know If not providing "Demo Account" the app will be rejected?

There is Demo Account for iCloud?

Thank you.

Comment: The reviewers will use their own iCloud account.

Comment: @rmaddy, can you put your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A demo iCloud account is not required.